# Find all pairs (x, y) in an unsorted array so that x + y = z

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have n numbers and a number z. I want to create an algorithm(pseudocode) to find if there are pairs (x,y) that x + y = z in O(nlogn).

I thought that i can run the quicksort algorithm. Then i will have 2 arrays: array1 (with elements < pivot) and array2 (with elements>pivot).
if the first element in array is < z then i can check all the other elements in array1 to find pairs that x+y=z.
else if the first element in array1 is >z then i go to array2 and make the same procedure.
Is my suggestion true?

Comment: When the array is already sorted, you can do it in O(n).

Comment: the array is unsorted. Sorry, i edit my question now

Comment: Are the numbers unique?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, sort the array.
Then set one pointer/index to each end of the sorted array.
If they sum up to `z`, you keep it and move both pointers towards the middle.
If the sum is smaller than `z`, you move the pointer on the small end towards the middle.
If the sum is larger than `z`, you move the pointer on the large end towards the middle.
When the pointers meet/pass, you're done.

Answer (score 3):

The idea with the pivot is not going to work, because there is no good candidate for a pivot, and because checking unsorted half-range would remain an O(n) task that needs to be done n/2 times, for the overall complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

You can do it in O(n) without sorting by adding all elements to a hash table, and then checking for each element `x` that `z-x` element also exists. A situation with `x=z/2` is a special case, because you need to verify that two `z/2` values exist in the input array.

Comment: yes i know that i can do this in O(n), but i want an algorithm to work in O(nlogn)

Comment: @dimitrisdimas1313 Sort in O(nlogn), then search from opposite ends for O(n). Overall complexity is going to remain O(nlogn).

Comment: This was a nice answer! Also, technically, if it's O(n) it is also O(nlogn) (but not the other way around).

Comment: @dimitrisdimas1313 What possible reason do you have for wanting it to be O(nlogn) over O(n)? Such a weird requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need be sorting an already sorted sequence, just searching it.

pseudocode:

```
sort(sequence) // O(NlogN) sorts are well known
for element in sequence: // O(N) loop
    target = z - element // constant (assuming fixed size arithmetic)
    if target > min_element and target < max_element: // constant
        found = binary_search(target, sequence) // O(LogN) search
```

complexity: O(NlogN (sort) + (N (loop) * LogN (Search))) = O(NlogN), as required